# Parsing a file with following a pattern

Tags: parsing, sed, awk, mediawiki

I need to parse a file with a mediawiki syntax (tables).

I know sed or awk could do it but I'm no expert of these.

I need to find the following pattern :

```
beginning_of_line| [[text]] ||  random_stuff_until_newline
```

There might be (or not) space between the pipes and the brakets. And I need a output the text

Any solutions for me ?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing text like that is like parsing XML or HTML. Regexes aren't really well suited for that type of document. You should try to find a Python or Perl module that is [suited for the job](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers).

However, here is a `sed` command that will work in the simple case you provided as an example.

```
sed 's/^[^|]*|[[:space:]]*\[\[\([^]]\+\)\]\].*/\1/' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

I would look for a Mediawiki parser. It must exist somewhere.

Failing that, if you have a grammar for mediawiki you can generate a parser using ANTLR or similiar depending on what kind of grammar it is.

If you don't have a grammar  or don't want to do that because of the learning curve then you need some reliable way to distinguish between what yo're calling "text and what you're calling random stuff. Are the pipes guaranteed to be there? If so in Java you can just do String.split() using the pipes as the argument to split.

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only proper parser of MediaWiki syntax is MediaWiki itself. There is no formal grammar or anything like that.

Comment: OK are you sure about that? So what you're saying is they hand coded a parser using a regexp library. It may be true. It's not true of HTML or CSS by way of comparison. Meh, if that's the case then you have to use regexp yourself. Java has a strong Regular  Expression library, as does Perl and AWK

Comment: I didn't look at the source code, so I'm not sure whether MediaWiki uses regexps (although I doubt it, the language is no regular). It seems there are many [alternate parsers](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers) and [some attempts to write a proper spec](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Markup_spec), but none of them are complete.

Comment: Well the regular expression concept does not require that the language or grammar be "regula" whatever you mean by that (not sure) . In the world of parsing it's generally either parsers created by parser generators which are fed a grammar or it's reg exp. In this case it seems to be reg exp so you should be able to find a reg exp to recognize  most anything they're  recognizing since that's how they're doing it I guess.

Comment: I mean the formal definition of a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language): a language that can be parsed by a formal regular expressions (which are simpler than regular expressions in libraries). And the language of MediaWiki markup is not regular, because you can have templates inside templates. And you can't parse a language like that by regular expressions alone.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^[^|]*|\s*\[\[\([^]]*\(][^]]*\)*\)]]\s*||.*/\1/;t;d' file
```